# Label of the control is jumping to the right side when resized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The generated HTML I have is this:

I put it in Bootply so you can just see and play with it easier, notice it has a small CSS section too:

http://www.bootply.com/NrxiDfZJdC

Problem is it is not "bootstrappy" enough! If you start making the window smaller the labels jump to the right side of the control.
What have I done that has caused this issue?

[image]

Comment: Was the right alignment not intended?  You do have `.text-right` on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of major problems here.

#### Right Alignment:

You have set this by adding `.text-right` on your labels.  Obviously this was meant for the desktop view only.  **Take it off of your labels and use a min-width media query to set the alignment** or override the alignment with max-width at small resolutions

#### Overflowing text boxes:

You didn't use a row.  You should most always use a row because it corrects the padding wit negative left and right margins.  You tried to fix this yourself by instead adding a class that removes the padding on the `.col-sm-4`.  The padding is there for a reason and should not be removed.  Even **adding in the row and removing the `.multi-row`** doesn't completely correct the issue, however.  When you do that you run into the text inputs being too wide.  That is because you added the `100%` width to the inputs.  This is not a bad thing per se, but it causes problems because you have used `span`s for your inner columns.  `span`s are naturally collapsed in width.  They don't fill their parents' container like `div`s do.  **Swap them for `div`s.**

#### Weird "Ext" label:

This is because you added a `margin-left: 85%` to the label to simulate the right alignment that the others have.  Just **remove that margin and add `text-right`** to this label like you have on all the other similar labels.

#### No padding:

After all that, you'll have no padding on smaller resolutions.  **Add a `.container` around your form.**

In the end, you should have this: http://www.bootply.com/uiPpBytre3

#### Demo:

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css);

.form-input{
  width :100%;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .form-group .text-right {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <br>

    <div class="row form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-1 text-right"><label class="control-label" for="Name">Name</label></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"><select class="form-control" id="nameadmin" name="nameadmin"><option>77881</option>
        <option>77882</option>
        <option>77883</option>
        <option>77884</option>
        <option>77885</option>
        </select></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
        <div>
          <input class="checkbox-inline" id="ShowEmailInFooter" name="ShowEmailInFooter" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="ShowEmailInFooter" type="hidden" value="false">
          <label class="control-label" for="Show_Email_in_Footer">Show Email in Footer</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-1 text-right"><label class="control-label" for="Email">Email</label></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input id="AdminEmail" name="AdminEmail" style="width:100%;padding-right:30px;" type="text" value="">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope  form-control-feedback" style="right: 10px; line-height: 27px; color: lightblue"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1">
        <div>
          <input class="checkbox-inline" id="ShowAdminPhone" name="ShowAdminPhone" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="ShowAdminPhone" type="hidden" value="false">
          <label class="control-label" for="Show_Admin_phone">Show Admin phone</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-1 text-right"><label class="control-label" for="Phone">Phone</label></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-5"><input class="form-input" id="AdminPhone" name="AdminPhone" type="text" value=""></div>
          <div class="col-sm-2 text-right"><label class="control-label" for="Ext">Ext</label></div>
          <div class="col-sm-5"><input class="form-input" id="AdminExt" name="AdminExt" type="text" value=""></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add responsive text align class `text-sm-right` instead of `text-right`

```
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    .text-sm-right { text-align: right; }
}
```

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/vpLDhg2QFh#)